# How do I force cxx11 ABI on Red Hat?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, name-mangling

I'm building a small .so library on Ubuntu 16.04 and Red Hat 7 using gcc 7.3. When I check the export symbol names using the nm command, I find that the library compiled on Ubuntu uses the cxx11 ABI but the library compiled on RedHat does not.

For example, the export symbol for a function compiled on Ubuntu looks like this.

```
_Z12customLoad3DPKN8nlohmann10basic_jsonISt3mapSt6vectorNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEblmdSaNS_14adl_serializerEEEPP11IVolumeDataPSA_
```

But the same export symbol when compiled on RedHat looks like this.

```
_Z12customLoad3DPKN8nlohmann10basic_jsonISt3mapSt6vectorSsblmdSaNS_14adl_serializerEEEPP11IVolumeDataPS4_
```

Both libraries use the same makefile. The code uses #define _GLIBCXX_USECXX11_ABI 1 and command line option -std=c++11. I’ve also tried using the -fabi-version option with different values, all with no effect. I can’t resolve this with the `#ifdef __cplusplus extern "C"` method because the functions use template class parameters.

How do I force gcc on RedHat to use the cxx11 ABI? I can’t use dual ABI linkage because the .so library is used as a plugin for an app that links at runtime to functions in the library using a hardcoded list of mangled names. The plugin won’t work on Red Hat because the mangled names don’t match the program’s expectations. How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure gcc 7 is used in red hat?

Comment: Sounds to me like this "plugin" is broken by design. Both Fedora/Red Hat, and I presume Ubuntu, include minor patches in their distributions' respective compilers ***and C++ libraries***. There is no guarantee, whatsoever, that C++ compiler even with the same base version, but on different Linux distributions, will produce identical name mangling. You cannot rely on mangled symbols.

Comment: @oblivion with devtoolset-7 it is. You can also get GCC 8 with devtoolset-8. Where I work we are using GCC 8 and C++17 on RHEL7 by way of devtoolset-8 - fully supported.

Comment: @JesperJuhl sure but is not enabled by default.

Comment: I'm positive that I'm using gcc 7.3. I installed it myself and the gcc -v command reports 7.3. I noticed that when I call gcc -v, it reports the option --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatable. Is this causing the old ABI to be used?

Comment: @Sam, when you say the plugin is 'broken by design', what would you recommend as a fix?

Comment: Use portable C ABI, and non-mangled symbols. This can be done with C++ code by declaring symbols as `extern "C" {`

Comment: Red Hat supplies antique software. Use a different operating system.

Comment: @SamVarshavchij As I mentioned in my original post, I can't use extern "C" { because all the exported functions use template class parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `libstdc++` C++11 ABI is not supported on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.  You have two options:

- Upgrade to Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8. Its system compiler defaults to the newer ABI.
- Rebuild the application on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7, using [Developer Toolset](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_developer_toolset/). The hybrid linkage model ensures that the application will run on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7. Only the old ABI is available, but this generally does not matter due to the rebuild because the result is internally consistent.